# How to display Current Time (Realtime) in iOS 14 Home Widget

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

I am developing an application for ios 14 Home Widget and I am facing a problem while showing the current time (digital clock) that the widget not getting updated every sec. As we all know, Apple does not allow to trigger timeline every second is there any other way to display the current time with the realtime updates?

I tried these methods but not works as expected

```
class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var dateIs = Date()
    
    init() {
        startTimer() // fetch data must be called at least once
    }
    private  func startTimer() { 
        let t = RepeatingTimer(timeInterval: 3)
                t.eventHandler = {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        // your UI update code
                        print("Timer Fired")
                     self.dateIs = Date()
                        WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() // reload timelines
                    }
                    if(false){   //I know this makes no sense, but it works. Go figure...
                        t.suspend()
                    }
                }
                t.resume()

    }
}


struct Provider: TimelineProvider {

    init() {
        networkManager = NetworkManager()
    }

    
    @AppStorage("storedData", store: UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.name"))
    var data: Data  = Data()
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> WidgetEntry {
        let entry = WidgetEntry(date: Date(), storedData: storedData[0], dateIs: networkManager.dateIs)
        return entry
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (WidgetEntry) -> Void) {
        
        guard let storedData: WidgetTemplate = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WidgetTemplate.self, from: data) else { return }
        let entry = WidgetEntry(date: Date(), storedData: storedData, dateIs: networkManager.dateIs)
          
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<WidgetEntry>) -> Void) {
    
        guard let storedData: WidgetTemplate = try? JSONDecoder().decode(WidgetTemplate.self, from: data) else { return }
        let entry = WidgetEntry(date: Date(), storedData: storedData, dateIs: networkManager.dateIs)
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        let refreshDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 5, to: currentDate)!
        
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry], policy:  .after(refreshDate))
        completion(timeline)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating time text label each minute in WidgetKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053733/updating-time-text-label-each-minute-in-widgetkit)

Answer (score 3):

You’re not allowed to refresh the Widget *every second*. That’s the limitation from Apple.

Best you can do is display a date with *seconds*
using the `timer` date style:

```
/// A style displaying a date as timer counting from now.
///
///     Text(event.startDate, style: .timer)
///
/// Example output:
///    2:32
///    36:59:01
public static let timer: Text.DateStyle
```

---

1. You need a simple `Entry` with a `Date` property:

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
}
```

2. Pass the *midnight* date for a given day in the `Entry` and refresh the timeline after the *next midnight*:

```
struct SimpleProvider: TimelineProvider {
    ...

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!
        let entries = [SimpleEntry(date: midnight)]
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

3. Display the date using the `timer` style:

```
struct SimpleWidgetEntryView: View {
    var entry: SimpleProvider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .timer)
    }
}
```

---

Note that when you refresh the timeline (either by specifying the `TimelineReloadPolicy` or by calling the `WidgetCenter`) you set the ***earliest*** time when the Widget will be refreshed.

It is not guaranteed to be refreshed ***at that specific time***.

Comment: This works as a timer, but not as a clock. Clock has format "hh:mm", but here I got format "mm:ss". Now thinking how is it possible to get clock format from these

Comment: @Maks I added an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053733/update-time-text-label-each-minute-widgetkit-swift/64054719#64054719).

Comment: @pawello2222 Yeah, it's perfect. but now I cant refresh the widget with new data like text color background image etc. by calling

    WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()

Comment: @user3634291 Why not? Just add more properties to the Entry.

Comment: Yeah I just updated something like this 

entries.append( WidgetEntry(date: entryDate, templateData: templateData))

Comment: But when I call WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines() this nothing gets updated. and I tried to remove for loop and added a single entry and its works. any idea?

Comment: @user3634291 Why entries.append? There should only be one entry in your case. And when the data changes just call WidgetCenter to reload. Remember you can’t refresh too often.

Comment: But as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64054719/3634291 to get a realtime clock update we need to append multiple

Comment: @user3634291 This is my other answer for another case (a clock with minutes only, no seconds). Please follow this answer.

Comment: Yeah my case is also similar to that i want to display a clock in hh: mm format

Comment: @user3634291 You’re not allowed to refresh the Widget every second. That’s the limitation from Apple. Best you can do is displaying a date with seconds.

Comment: Ok but is it possible to reinstate the timeline data from the parent app button click? from this answer stackoverflow.com/a/64054719/3634291?

Comment: @user3634291 Yes, just call the WidgetCenter to reload. But please see the note at the bottom of my answer. You may ask the Widget to refresh the timeline but it may not always do it immediately.

Comment: Alright, let us display with seconds for now. I believe its the best way without refreshing the entire widget.

Comment: @pawello2222 Can we at least convert this time to 12 Hours format?

Comment: Can I customzied the timer style

Comment: @myatmins You can choose between the different styles: `time`, `date`, `relative`, `offset` and `timer`. But I don't think you can customise a style - you can try to *mix* them though (eg. by displaying two Texts next to each other).

Comment: Just throwing this in as  I couldn't find it anywhere. You can use the `.relative` to show something similar to "2 min ago". E.g.  `Text("\(entry.date, style: .relative) ago")`