# SwiftUI, WidgetKit: Format date with timer style

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

I have a working clock widget. To achieve that, I have created a timeline that updates once a day.

```
func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!
        let entries = [SimpleEntry(date: midnight)]
        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
        completion(timeline)
    }
```

The widget shows the clock like this:

```
var body: some View {
        
     VStack {
         Text(entry.date, style: .timer)            
     }         
}
```

I chose this approach over creating a timeline of entries every minute, as I read in the documentation that the system doesn't promise to update the widget as requested, but according to a budget.

The label shows something like this:

**14:30:25**

How can I make it show

**2:30 PM** instead

Comment: Use another init for `Text` like [init(:format:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:format:)) or [init(:formatter:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:formatter:)-1v7mr)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson But then I won't have the functionality of progressing time that the .timer gives me. Is there a way to combine both?

Comment: But if you style something as a timer (that is a counter) does it makes sense to show AM/PM since it is a duration? Shouldn't you use `.time` then if it is the actual time you want to show?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The reason I used the timer format is so I won't drain the budget for the widget refreshes as it is written here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64053733/updating-time-text-label-each-minute-in-widgetkit

Comment: I understand but I think you will have to accept that if you use `.timer` then am/pm makes no sense so you can’t format the output that way.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I might accept it in the near future. But maybe some alternative approach will surface in answers and comments...

Answer (score -3):

You can use [DateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter) or directly with [Text.init(_:formatter:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:formatter:)-1v7mr).
Also you can use [Text.init(_:format:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:format:))

Comment: But then I won't have the functionality of progressing time that the .timer gives me. Is there a way to combine both?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).