# SwiftUI Widget DateStyle Custom Format

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

Just wondering if there is a way to apply a custom format for the DateStyle comp within SwiftUI's Text UI. For Example just the minutes or seconds like you would when using a DateFormatter. I want to display the dynamic dates for a Widget but it only offers a limited number of options. Why is this and has anyone found a way around this?

Apple talk more about **Displaying Dynamic Dates** here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/keeping-a-widget-up-to-date

Comment: See [Updating time text label each minute in WidgetKit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64053733/8697793) or [How to display Current Time (Realtime) in iOS 14 Home Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64053270/8697793)

Comment: AFAIK you can choose between the different styles: `time`, `date`, `relative`, `offset` and `timer`. But I don't think you can *customise* a style - you can try to mix them though (eg. by displaying two Texts next to each other).

Comment: Yeah I know about the different styles. Pretty annoying that we can't customise it. I wonder what the reasoning is

Comment: iOS 15.0 introduced [Date.FormatStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/date/formatstyle) that enables substantial customizability of date and time format styles.

Answer (score 10):

You won't like this answer, but as of iOS 14, the answer is there's no way to customize the relative style for `Text`. The `relative` style is new in iOS 14, and as always, Apple provide the bare minimum feature.

For now, you have only these choices:

1. Use other [Text.DateStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/datestyle), if they work for you
2. Fallback to `DateFormatter` (and other formatters) with the tradeoff that widget can only refresh couple of times in a day

Hopefully this won't be the answer with iOS 15 or later.

Comment: Sadly no change for iOS15. Bare minimum, clumsy formatting is all we get for dynamic date styles, and based on past experience with Apple, quite possibly all we'll ever get.

Comment: Sadly no change for iO16 either.. :(

Comment: And it’s broken in ios16. 

Comment: Aaaaand still no change in iOS 17